# Is there a way to stream only audio from nginx's RTMP module?

Tags: nginx, audio-streaming

I'm very satisfied with nginx's RTMP module; I like the way it works and the way it does what it does. I thought it would be a perfect live audio streaming platform, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to use nginx's RTMP module as a pure audio server. Pure audio, mind you, no video, though I don't mind as to the codec or format used. So is there a way to configure nginx RTMP to serve live, only audio streams?

Comment: What's the problem in having a one by one pixel video stream? What did you try to just stream audio and what happened? Did you simply try to just feed it an audio stream?

Comment: Did you find a solution?